# Backup file APFS - Access to files inside Backup Cluster for Windows Transfer!

Tags: windows, backup, ssd, data-recovery, file

My wife had some issues recently wrecking her Library cluster on her Mac, which was quite the wrong move to make space due to CalendarAgent spamming the drive space till the Mac crashes due to "no storage space left" issue.

So ... About flusterclucking 3 days to solve Apple's worst data recovery software ever ... I've managed backing up her personal data from the drive. Now. I am have an issue not transfering the backup to her Win10 PC, though we have an issue "unpacking" the 5.Apple_APFS file, where her music, pictures, medic-studies and so on are.

Does anyone know if that file is encrypted for good, so only a backup-restore on a new/freshly installed MacOS would solve this mess, or are there any kind of "Mac Tools for Windows" like "APFS for Windows by Paragon Software" helping in this another segment of frustration Apple did here (I also tried taking the HDD and putting it into an Adapter (Retina/Whatever A-SSD to SATA Adapter) to read the files unencrypted, but that didn't work at all - crashed her Windows Desktop entirely after trying to activate the drive as a regular internal harddrive.

For any kind of help, we are thankful.

Additional details: External harddrive, which has been used as a backup-transfere storage, was APFS NOT encrypted, standard format, drive didn't use any kind of secure-/lock-password nor the files/folders on the drive.
If this helps.

Comment: Your first paragraph has me quite perplexed and Apple provides no data recovery software. That would be something like Data Rescue. Are you seeking software to fix this or a recommendation which company does recovery on bare drives? This might need a massive edit to have a clear problem statement.

Comment: If you’re looking for a windows tool to read APFS - https://superuser.com/questions/1157631/how-to-access-an-apfs-volume-on-windows-machine

Answer (score 0):

If your need is windows 10 (or other recent version) to read an Apple APFS drive, this software should do the trick: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/